# how can i get the value of a variable outside the arrow function in mern stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

i want to get the value of this variable outside the function **const custDetail = await registeredUser.findOne(req.params);**

```
const dashboardReq = async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        const regCust = await registeredUser.findOne({ mobile: req.params.mobile });

    if (regCust == null) {
      console.log("No user found");
    } else {
      const custDetail = await registeredUser.findOne(req.params);
    }
    res.status(201).json({
      status: "success",
      data: { regCust },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "fail",
      data: next(error),
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: you must declare it globally before setting it's value. Outside: `let custDetail` then remove `const` inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** a simple way to pass data to another function using `res.locals`

router:

```
router.get('getDashboardRef/:mobile', userCtl.dashboardReq, userCtl.nextFunction)
```

dashboardReq

```
const dashboardReq = async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        res.locals.regCust = await registeredUser.findOne({ mobile: req.params.mobile });

    if (!res.locals.regCust) {
      console.log("No user found");
      throw new Error("No user found")
    } else {
      res.locals.custDetail = await registeredUser.findOne(req.params);
     next()
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "fail",
      data: error,
    });
  }
};
```

nextFunction

```
const nextFunction = (req, res) => {
  //do stuff with res.locals.custDetail
 res.status(201).json({
      status: "success",
      data: { res.locals.regCust },
    });
}
```

Comment: here check the user in my database if he found then I want to pass the detail of the user to other function

Comment: you should resolve the http request in the other function, or use this function as a middleware and call `next`. Can you post the function you want to call next? is the intended flow: find user >> find user details >> pass details to other function >> do something with details >> respond to http request ?

Comment: please check my edits

Comment: what is userctrl1 and 2 from the code

Comment: I'm assuming your route looked something like that, please post your route and the function you want to call next, that way we can answer more clearly

Comment: my problem is  1st I will check the user from the database and then I will post some data into another DB table by using user detail through other function.

Comment: i am new in node js plz help

Comment: what does your route look like?

Answer (score 0):

try to revisit your design since the variable custDetail needs to exist inside the route itself

if this is supposed to be memoized, then maintain a map with some unique identifier from req.params with the result from registeredUser.findOne